# XML-RPC with Lazarus freepascal

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-rpc, lazarus, freepascal

I know there are plenty of freepascal xml tutorials and posts, but nothing I found so far seem to do the job for me.
I am building Lazarus desktop app to connect through API to Odoo, get some data, process and respond.
The structure of xml response is quite difficult (at least to me) to work with.
The example response is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <array>
          <data>
            <value>
              <struct>
                <member>
                  <name>create_date</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>2016-03-30 09:05:23</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>file_name</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>O156AP000100</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>dispatch_date</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>2016-04-04</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>height</name>
                  <value>
                    <int>0</int>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>custom_option_mapping_ids</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data />
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>message_ids</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data />
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>message_summary</name>
                  <value>
                    <string />
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>create_uid</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data>
                        <value>
                          <int>7</int>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                          <string>My 1st years</string>
                        </value>
                      </data>
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>display_name</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>artwork.job,283</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>message_is_follower</name>
                  <value>
                    <boolean>1</boolean>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>production_date</name>
                  <value>
                    <boolean>0</boolean>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>message_last_post</name>
                  <value>
                    <boolean>0</boolean>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>id</name>
                  <value>
                    <int>283</int>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>width</name>
                  <value>
                    <int>0</int>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>file_path</name>
                  <value>
                    <string>2016-04-04/Table Rate/1</string>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>text_colour</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data>
                        <value>
                          <int>489</int>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                          <string>Text Colour: Fuchsia Pink</string>
                        </value>
                      </data>
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>text_lines</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data>
                        <value>
                          <int>1686</int>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                          <int>16380</int>
                        </value>
                      </data>
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>sale_order_id</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data>
                        <value>
                          <int>368</int>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                          <string>SO156</string>
                        </value>
                      </data>
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                  <name>text_font</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data>
                        <value>
                          <int>492</int>
                        </value>
                        <value>
                          <string>Font: Verdana</string>
                        </value>
                      </data>
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
              </struct>
            </value>
          </data>
        </array>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

The problem is that the values are without unique tags, or ID's.
What I am trying to do is to access values by their names. The problem I am facing is that there are no ID's for the values etc, and some parts are arrays.
I have been trying with

```
variables:= Doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('member');
fname:=variables[3].FindNode('value').TextContent;
```

but this will fail if structure changes and doesn't really take arrays into account.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not a file, but Odoo server xml-rpc response so stream. I am capturing it as a printable text and the example is above.

Comment: I know. FWIW, I deleted my comment before I saw your reply.

Comment: Probably you should to start at [Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit) I am not familiar with web services, just a guess.

Comment: I went through this as well before. It's a first time I am dealing with API and I could not find anything I could think of using in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I have found an answer myself. Thx anyone who contributed.
I know if it's not the most elegant way of doing this, it does the job though.
I made to separate functions running through the xml, onc returning string, other one array.

```
type
TStringArray = array of string; 

...

  public 
function extractVar(Doc1: TXMLDocument; searchvar:string): String;
function extractArray(Doc1: TXMLDocument; searchvar:string): TStringArray; 

...

var
textLines: TStringArray; 

...

function TAThread.extractArray(Doc1: TXMLDocument; searchvar:string): TStringArray;
var
c,v:integer;
Name,value:string;
myNodes: TDOMNodeList;
subNodes: TDOMNodeList;
 begin
 c:=0;
  try
   myNodes:= Doc1.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('member');
    for c:=0 to myNodes.Count-1 do
     begin
      Name:= myNodes[c].FindNode('name').TextContent;
        if (Name=searchvar) then begin
         try
          subNodes:= myNodes[c].GetChildNodes;
          subNodes:= subNodes[1].GetChildNodes;
          subNodes:= subNodes[0].GetChildNodes;
          subNodes:= subNodes[0].GetChildNodes;
          v:=0;
          SetLength(Result, subNodes.Count);
           for v:=0 to subNodes.Count-1 do
            begin
             Result[v]:= subNodes[v].TextContent;
            end;

          finally
           subNodes.Free;
          end;
         end;
       end;
  finally
  myNodes.Free;
  end;
end;

function TAThread.extractVar(Doc1: TXMLDocument; searchvar:string): String;
var
c:integer;
Name:string;
myNodes: TDOMNodeList;
 begin
 c:=0;
  try
  myNodes:= Doc1.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('member');
   for c:=0 to myNodes.Count-1 do
    begin
    Name:= myNodes[c].FindNode('name').TextContent;
     if (Name=searchvar) then begin
      result:= myNodes[c].FindNode('value').TextContent;
     end;
   end;
  finally
  myNodes.Free;
  end;
end;
```